# Regex to match a 28 character ID string with special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a little app that reads in some log files made by another application. In these files lines similar to this are being processed:

```
 ban added reason='Posting links to malware websites' cluid='oNNtrNGo6kdxNRshT8MiHlq4wR8=' bantime=0 by client 'Someone'(id:4)
```

Currently I have a little bit of Regex `\w{27}=` that will get the cluid value in that string. The cluids are always 27 characters long with an '=' at the end. However there are some of those ID's that have special characters within the ID itself, example: `IVz0tUZThCdbBnCWjf+axoMqVTM=` (notice the '+' character) This means that my regex does not match this ID.

What do I need to add to the regex in order for it to match both ID's?

Comment: Thanks! This works, although I don't understand what the `(?==)` bit means?

Comment: If the param name is always `cluid`, I'd recommend a simple `cluid='([^']+)'`.

Comment: @sday03 it's a positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by an equal sign.

Comment: @sday03 It is base64 encoded string, so it doesn't have to end with `=` everytime. It is `A0-D3-6D-AC-D1-A8-EA-47-71-35-1B-21-4F-C3-22-1E-5A-B8-C1-1F` in your case

Comment: @EZI thanks for pointing that one out! I think that will be useful to know down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're interested in only cluid's value (that's in between single quotes).  You can try this pattern:

```
"cluid='([^']{27}=)'"
```

it captures 27 characters that are not a single quote (assuming a single quote cannot be part of the value) followed by the equal sign into capture group 1.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string line1 = "ban added reason='Posting links to malware websites' cluid='oNNtrNGo6kdxNRshT8MiHlq4wR8=' bantime=0 by client 'Someone'(id:4)";
        Match m = Regex.Match(line1, "cluid='([^']{27}=)'");
        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
        }

        string line2 = "ban added reason='Posting links to malware websites' cluid='IVz0tUZThCdbBnCWjf+axoMqVTM=' bantime=0 by client 'Someone'(id:4)";
        m = Regex.Match(line2, "cluid='([^']{27}=)'");
        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
oNNtrNGo6kdxNRshT8MiHlq4wR8=
IVz0tUZThCdbBnCWjf+axoMqVTM=
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FL8b4x)